# Why does joda time update the time and offset when java time doesn't?

Tags: java, jodatime, java-time, jsr310

I can't seem to figure out why joda time is updating the time and offset hours after daylight saving time, but java time doesn't.

```
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime("2016-04-05T10:06:21.636-05:00").withDayOfWeek(5);

    TemporalField dayOfWeek = WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek();
    OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2016-04-05T10:06:21.636-05:00").with(dayOfWeek, 5);
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2016-04-05T10:06:21.636-05:00").with(dayOfWeek, 5);

    System.out.println("dateTime:         " + dateTime); // 2016-04-08T11:06:21.636-04:00
    System.out.println("offsetDateTime:   " + offsetDateTime); // 2016-04-08T10:06:21.636-05:00
    System.out.println("zonedDateTime:    " + zonedDateTime); // 2016-04-08T10:06:21.636-05:00
```

Comment: Maybe because the java8 jsr310 implementation is close to yoda time, but not exactly the same? There are subtle differences between the two ... probably that would be one of them.

Comment: I guess: You did not provide a time zone, only an offset to both, the offset date time and the zoned date time instances. In both cases, they don't have any clue about daylight saving times. Probably, you must provide a time zone when constructing the zoned date time object, and it might work as you expect.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Thanks. That was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Time zone versus offset

You did not provide a time zone, only an offset to both, the offset date time and the zoned date time instances. In both cases, they don't have any clue about daylight saving times as this is an information of the time zone.

So you must provide a time zone when constructing the zoned date time object, and it then it works as you expect.

Comment: In other words, an offset-from-UTC is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds. A time zone is *much* more. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.